# NoSuchMethodError with EmbeddedKafkaCluster

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am trying to unit test the Kafka Streams implementation by using EmbeddedKafkaCluster (kafka-junit) but I keep getting the weird error. I suspect this could be due to dependency conflict. Have tried a couple of permutations but nothing seems to be working and hence thought to seek expert advice

I resolved the error with curator by adding dependency separately for the right version. However now I am stuck with this. I tried different streams/kafka version too but the error with kafka-clients just refuses to go off.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bell.sa.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-kafka-streams-module</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>spring-kafka-streams-module</name>
    <description>Spring Kafka Consumer Library to be included in any application requiring to stream Kafka Messages</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kafka.streams.version>2.3.0</kafka.streams.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
      <version>${kafka.streams.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.curator/curator-test-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.mguenther.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-junit</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
            <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig.(Ljava/util/Map;Z)V

Comment: Following is the test I was trying to run
    '@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)'
    '@SpringBootTest'
    '@DirtiesContext'
    'public class KafkaStreamsUnitTest {'

 '@ClassRule'
 'public static final EmbeddedKafkaCluster embeddedKafkaCluster = 
EmbeddedKafkaCluster.provisionWith(EmbeddedKafkaClusterConfig.useDefaults());'

      '@Test'
 'public void testStream() throws Exception {'
  'try {
   streamService.startStreamProcess();'

Comment: Description: An attempt was made to call the method org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig.<init> but it does not exist. Its class, org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig, is available from the following locations:
    jar:file:/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/2.0.0/kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar!/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClientConfig.class
It was loaded from the following location:
    file:.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/2.0.0/kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar

Comment: How did you resolve this?